# UIStoryboard Reference and root view controller

Tags: ios, objective-c, uiviewcontroller, uistoryboard, uistoryboardsegue

I have a "Main" storyboard, inside this storyboard i have a Storyboard reference entity that links to another storyboard "Login". I'm noticing that when i attempt to access the view currently onscreen with the following:

```
[[[[UIApplication sharedApplication]delegate]window]rootViewController]
```

It's returning me the view on the "Main" Storyboard, but if i attempt to push a UIAlertController on this view i get the following error:

```
Warning: Attempt to present <UIAlertController: 0x1839a000> on <ViewController: 0x17633ad0> whose view is not in the window hierarchy!
```

Is there a reason i can't push this view on top, if not how do i get the actual uiviewcontroller currently being displayed from the "Login" storyboard?

Comment: can you describe on which storyboard controller you are presenting the alert controller where you got the error? i mean the code lines for presenting and that controller is from which storyboard?

Comment: are you want to get top view controller ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you are presenting `UIAlertController` from your `viewDidload` then it may happen like this because when view is loading at that time it is not in windows hierarchy until it load completely.

Second thing you must present `UIAlertController` on top most view controller like,

```
 [self presentViewController......];
```

not on windows rootViewController. So, it's depends hows you are doing this.

Comment: Hi Ketan, thanks for the info. I reworked my code to user delegates to push the corresponding behaviour into the view controller instantiating the view and that seemed to work. I'd still like to know why i can't access the view that is currently visible though, as the rootviewcontroller should tell me the current displaying uiviewcontroller, from here i could created a variable and then use the variable to present the view controller.

Comment: in `viewDidload` view is being loading not and after completion of that method the view is completely load on window, so `viewWillAppear` or `viewDidAppear` is called after that and at that time viewController's view is already loaded on `window`

Answer (score 0):

plz use this

```
 -(id)getTopViewController{


               UIViewController *topController = [UIApplication sharedApplication].keyWindow.rootViewController;

                while (topController.presentedViewController) {
                    topController = topController.presentedViewController;
                }
                if (![topController isKindOfClass:[NSNull class]]) {

                    return topController;
                }



        }
```

use this method like this

```
 UIViewController *viewOb = [self getTopViewController];
```

use **viewOb** to presentViewController.